# Employee attendance calendar report design in iReport

Tags: mysql, sql

I have different tables for track the employee attendance and holidays all things are done and working fine now I want to create a report for employee monthly calendar report facing some issues.

**First thing is that**

**All tables are:**

**1. hr_employee**

**2. hr_biometric attendance**

**1. hr_employee_leave**

**1. hr_employee_visits**

**1. hr_holidays**

**1. Before 15 dates all Saturdays are count as working days after 15 dates all Saturdays are company holidays**

**2. In holiday records are in the date range from date and to date not single date holidays same for all other tables**

I have created a query but it retrieves multiple records, and it's a hard query for me to write. How can I do this?

Here is query:

```
    SET @fromDate = "2019-12-01";
SET @toDate = "2019-12-31";
SET @empId = 2814;
SET @recordStatus = "ATT";
SELECT 
att.time_checked AS checkedTIme, @recordStatus
FROM
hr_employee emp 
JOIN hr_biometric_attendance att ON att.`employee_id` = emp.id
WHERE emp.id = @empId
AND att.`time_checked` BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate

UNION
SELECT v.selected_date, "HD"  FROM 
(SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date FROM
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
,
(SELECT hDay.date_from df, hDay.date_to dt FROM `hr_holiday` hDay WHERE hDay.date_from >= @fromDate AND hDay.date_to <= @toDate) hDayQ
WHERE selected_date BETWEEN hDayQ.df AND hDayQ.dt

UNION
SELECT v1.selected_date1, "EV" FROM 
(SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t41.i*10000 + t31.i*1000 + t21.i*100 + t11.i*10 + t01.i) selected_date1 FROM
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t01,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t11,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t21,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t31,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t41) v1
,
(SELECT hEmpV.date_from df, hEmpV.date_to dt FROM `hr_employee_visit` hEmpV WHERE hEmpV.employee_id = @empId) hEmpVQ
WHERE selected_date1 BETWEEN hEmpVQ.df AND hEmpVQ.dt


UNION
SELECT v2.selected_date2, "EL" FROM 
(SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t42.i*10000 + t32.i*1000 + t22.i*100 + t12.i*10 + t02.i) selected_date2 FROM
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t02,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t12,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t22,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t32,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t42) v2
,
(SELECT hEmpL.date_from df, hEmpL.date_to dt FROM `hr_employee_leave` hEmpL WHERE hEmpL.employee_id = @empId) hEmpLQ
WHERE selected_date2 BETWEEN hEmpLQ.df AND hEmpLQ.dt

UNION DISTINCT
SELECT v3.selected_date3, (SELECT IF(DAYNAME(v3.selected_date3) ='Sunday' OR (DAYOFMONTH(v3.selected_date3) >= 15 AND DAYNAME(v3.selected_date3) ='saturday'),'H','W'))
FROM 
(SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t43.i*10000 + t33.i*1000 + t23.i*100 + t13.i*10 + t03.i) selected_date3 FROM
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t03,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t13,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t23,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t33,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t43) v3
WHERE selected_date3 BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate

ORDER BY `checkedTIme`;
```

Here is the erd tables:

[image]

Here is image for expected result report:

[image]

Here is Jasper result of above query:

[image]

Comment: Rather than using query to generate calendar table, why don't you just create one? Then your query will be much shorter and easier to maintain.

Comment: @ tcadidot0 please help me and suggest me how to work on it I am new in ireport

Comment: I'm talking about your mysql query. Refer this fiddle on how you can use your existing calendar query to create a calendar table https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qVgmfDaVUszABAyFzH7iUS/0

Comment: Then you can change your query from these parts `SELECT v.selected_date, "HD"  FROM 
(SELECT ADDDATE  ... )` to just `SELECT v.selected_date, "HD"  FROM 
calendar` instead.

Comment: @tcadidot0 please help me to generate above report from a query please

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in the comment, to simplify the query you should create a dedicated `calendar` table so you can shorten your query. Refer: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qVgmfDaVUszABAyFzH7iUS/0

Once that's done, you can re-write your query as following:

```
SET @fromDate = "2019-12-01";
SET @toDate = "2019-12-31";
SET @empId = 2814;
SET @recordStatus = "ATT";

SELECT att.time_checked AS checkedTIme, @recordStatus FROM hr_employee emp 
JOIN hr_biometric_attendance att ON att.`employee_id` = emp.id
WHERE emp.id = @empId
AND att.`time_checked` BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate

UNION
SELECT v.selected_dates, "HD"  FROM calendar v JOIN
(SELECT hDay.date_from df, hDay.date_to dt FROM `hr_holiday` hDay 
WHERE hDay.date_from >= @fromDate AND hDay.date_to <= @toDate) hDayQ
ON selected_dates BETWEEN hDayQ.df AND hDayQ.dt

UNION
SELECT v1.selected_dates, "EV" FROM calendar v1 JOIN
(SELECT hEmpV.date_from df, hEmpV.date_to dt FROM `hr_employee_visit` hEmpV 
WHERE hEmpV.employee_id = @empId) hEmpVQ
ON selected_dates BETWEEN hEmpVQ.df AND hEmpVQ.dt

UNION
SELECT v2.selected_dates, "EL" FROM calendar v2 JOIN
(SELECT hEmpL.date_from df, hEmpL.date_to dt FROM `hr_employee_leave` hEmpL 
WHERE hEmpL.employee_id = @empId) hEmpLQ
ON selected_dates BETWEEN hEmpLQ.df AND hEmpLQ.dt

UNION DISTINCT
SELECT v3.selected_dates, (SELECT IF(DAYNAME(v3.selected_dates) ='Sunday' 
OR (DAYOFMONTH(v3.selected_dates) >= 15 AND DAYNAME(v3.selected_dates) ='saturday'),'H','W')) 
FROM calendar v3
WHERE selected_dates BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate

ORDER BY `checkedTIme`;
```

Now it's much easier to read then you can start with building your final query.

Comment: thanks for that but I facing issues in my final query this I also have done please help me to build my final query

Comment: helps me to build the final query.

Comment: What is your expected result? Is it the first image @sarfarazahmed?

Comment: @ tcadidot0 yes

Comment: I mentioned the image title for the expected result.

Comment: Please post result from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on each of your working table in text and not as image and include a data sample `empId = 2814` for december 2019. It's better if you can create a fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: did not get what do you mean do you need sample data?

Comment: here is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cLrgNDEp41yZC1n3PLYgm7/0

Comment: @sarfarazahmed unfortunately the fiddle you provide are just table structures without data. I'm not able to do much on that because it will take a good chunk of my time to recreate the data. What I can do instead is this: as I'm seeing your expected output, it seems like you're aiming to get two results, one is the calendar date filled with checkin/out time and the other is a summarized info at the bottom. If so, try to tackle one issue first then the other. Once you have both working query then you figure out how to combine them. Good luck